# How to pack Custom (Compound) View into the library (Maven)

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-library

I have created custom compound view. Everything works pretty good. Now I want to put in one library to use it in my other projects.

There are a lot of libraries like this on GitHub and also available for downloading from Maven repositories.

There are Java class file, layout file, dimension XML file and attribute file.

I know that I should create a library project, but what do I have to do next? How do I push it to Maven repository to use it like any other library just by setting a dependency in my gradle file?

Comment: Fixed grammar and typos.